# Send an email three days before eventStartTime

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jakarta-ee

I have a mysql table as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eventName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventType` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventStartDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventStartTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventEndDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventEndTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventoptions` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need to send an email three days before eventStartTime. I need query to get the event, I hope to through event get the user and send email. Can I do that using  DATE_SUB(), 
But how can I do that? I am very bad at sql.

I use Mysql connector Java.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT * from events where date_add(curdate(),INTERVAL 3 days)=eventStartTime
```

This will give you all events which are 3 days from now.

Comment: I get an ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION planner.currdate does not exist.

Comment: It should be like this. SELECT * from events where date_add(curdate(),INTERVAL 3 day)=eventStartTime; And INTERVAL 3 day not days. But it was a complete and very informative answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in sql

http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364726/Job-Scheduling-in-J2EE-Applications

Comment: Well, I am using quartz, but I can't figure this out. If I can get previous date of three days, I can fire trigger on that day, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can derive the email time from the eventStartDate and the eventStartTime as follows:

```
SELECT CONCAT(eventStartDate - INTERVAL 3 DAY, ' ', eventStartTime)
```

However, this will not solve the problem of sending emails. You'll need a script than runs every so often, or some scheduler to send emails out when the email date arrives. You might consider storing the email send date/time as another field in your table, like emailSendDate

Consider using datetime fields instead of separate date and time fields. You can always parse out the various parts (the date, time, hour, year, etc) using MySQL functions.

Comment: INTERVAL 3 days - Can you explain this?

Comment: "+ INTERVAL" or "- INTERVAL" is another syntax for date math in MySQL without using DATE_ADD or DATE_SUB. Try SELECT "2012-05-30" - INTERVAL 3 DAY - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add